# What's wrong with my math in this function to update the position of a planet near a star?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

Initially the code seems to work as the planet curves toward the star, but then as it should either get pulled into the star or make an orbit, it just gets pushed away in the opposite direction. What am I doing wrong? It seems like the change in behavior happens when the sign of distance changes.

```
xPos += t * velocity/10000 * cos(direction / 180 * 3.14);
yPos += t * velocity/10000 * sin(direction / 180 * 3.14);

double gravity = 1000;
double starX = 1920/2;
double starY = 1080/2;

double deltaX = xPos - starX;
double deltaY = yPos - starY;
double distance = sqrt(pow(deltaX, 2) + pow(deltaY, 2));
int modifier = 1;
if (xPos > starX){
    modifier = -1;
}
double angle = atan(deltaY / deltaX) * 180 / 3.14;

xPos += t * gravity / pow(distance,2) * modifier * cos(angle / 180 * 3.14);
yPos += t * gravity / pow(distance,2) * modifier * sin(angle / 180 * 3.14);
```

xPos and yPos is the current position of the planet. t is the time since the last update. velocity and direction are the initial velocity and angle that the planet begins at. This force never changes since we are in space. gravity is the gravitational constant. starX and starY is the position of the star and distance is the distance between the star and the planet. angle is the angle between the star and the planet (I have a feeling that this is what is causing the unwanted behavior.)

I apologize if this is the wrong place for this question but I figured it was the right place since this is more of a math question than a programming one.

Comment: Is this a matlab code>

Comment: No, this is C++.

Comment: Do you need an x modifier and a y modifier

Comment: Would it be easier to keep the speed as a vector as well? `xSpeed` and `ySpeed` instead of `velocity` and `direction`. Then update those using the acceleration by the force of gravity. That's how I always code gravity sims.

Comment: IOW I think your physics is incorrect.

Comment: I agree with Jyrki.  You've got the physics wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work at least approximately. The granularity of time may cause the planet not to follow a closed orbit. To improve precision you should use a smaller $\Delta t$ and/or learn something about the numerical analysis of handling this type of differential equations more accurately.

Initialize variables (run tests to find combos that work for `DeltaT`):

```
DeltaT= ; (=time between frames)
xPos= ; (= x-coordinate of the planet at the beginning)
yPos= ; (= y-coordinate of the planet at the beginning)
xSpeed= ;  (= x-component of the planet's speed at the beginning)
ySpeed= ;  (= y-component of the planet's speed at the beginning)
```

Then a `Do - Until` loop in pseudocode (comments on lines starting with a %-sign):

```
Do
% update the planet's position
xPos=xPos+DeltaT*xSpeed;
yPos=yPos+DeltaT*ySpeed;
% calculate the current relative position to the star and the acceleration due to gravity
DeltaX=xPos-xStar;
DeltaY=yPos-yStar;
distance=sqrt(pow(DeltaX,2)+pow(DeltaY,2));
GravityMagnitude=GravityConst*StarMass/pow(distance,2);
% update the planet's speed
xSpeed=xSpeed-DeltaT*GravityMagnitude*DeltaX/distance;
ySpeed=ySpeed-DeltaT*GravityMagnitude*DeltaY/distance;
Until EndOfSimulation;
```

The acceleration caused by gravity is a vector. It's magnitude follows the inverse square law, but we need to break that down to $x/y$-components as well. This is exactly what the multipliers `DeltaX/distance` (and same for $y$) achieve.

Once you are happy with this it's time for some additions! Introduce several planets/stars. All moving, all being affected by the gravity of all the others. Trust me, even with three celestial bodies (of comparable masses) strange things will happen. Enjoy!

Comment: You probably want to add tests for checking if the distance becomes too small. Division by zero is not fun.

Comment: A followup on the comment about more sophisticated methods: the real model obeys conservation laws. For instance, the sum of the kinetic and gravitational potential energy is constant. Naive numerical methods like the one above usually do not obey a corresponding conservation law exactly. More sophisticated methods build the conservation law into the structure of the method.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Ian. I hazard a guess that this will help the OP. I have been trying to simulate some 3-body problems myself, so I would like to learn more. I know that slingshot effects occur, but would like to be sure that what I see is not a consequence of a granularity error. Can you give a buzzword for me to look up - or a link even?

Comment: The basic buzzword is "geometric integrator". A somewhat more specific buzzword for this setting is a "symplectic integrator" (since celestial mechanics can be treated as a Hamiltonian system).